# Minimum of $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-3x^2)$ in $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to show that the given function $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-3x^2)$ does not have a minimum in $(0,0)$.
I tried to it like this:

Look at $c(t)=(t,2t^2) $ and $f(c(t))=-t^4$

So we obtain that for all t that are not zero: $f(c(t))<0$

Can I conclude from this that f doesn't have a minimum in $(0,0)$?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Two questions for you: (i) What does it mean to say a point is a _minimum_ of a function? (ii) Together with (i), do your observations allow you to answer your own question?

Comment: It means that there exists a close delta neighborhood so that for points close to (0,0): $f(x)>f(0,0)$  holds for all x in the close delta-neighborhood.

Comment: With $f(c(t))$ we found a point where this definition is not fulfilled. Thus f does not have a minimum in $(0,0)$.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that looks good (though the strict inequality should be non-strict, $f(x,y) \geq f(0,0)$...). The additional detail to verify is that every neighborhood of the origin intersects your parabola $y = 2x^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)